# Clustering - Need to group points as I zoom out

Tags: arcgis-online, clustering, arcgis-online-basemaps

I do not have much experience with ArcGIS Online but there is a work that must be done.

I have a groups of points and they represent addresses where a certain work has been or not performed. I need to develop a map to show, per area as the user zooms out, how many points have the work done and how many need to do it.

Showing it as a pie chart will be the ideal, but also with just numbers is OK (see example). So far I have tried analysis - summarize data - aggregate points, but the result is not what I need.

I cannot find a way to do the clustering without having to modify the code (because I am null programming).

Is there any way to do it?

[image]

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=layers_point_clustering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't do any linking because I'm on my phone (nor do I yet have enough points to make this a comment), but really it sounds like you should do a couple hot spot analyses (spatial analyst extension) to get different "scales" (a result which will look the way you want for a given scale), then serve those layers to your web map, and set the scale range so that different result feature classes show at different zoom levels.